# Обновить/загрузить актуальный файл из SVN

Tags: svn, linux

Всем привет )
Недавно, пришлось экстренно поменять кое-что в файле минуя коммит в SVN.
То есть, заместо того, чтобы на локальном компьютере произвести изменения и закоммитить это, я изменил сразу на сервере файл (на то были причины).

Скажите, как мне теперь загрузить файл с сервера на компьютер?

Comment: svn update?

Comment: @Gorets не помогает. Как я понимаю, на сервере его нужно как-то закомитить, но не пойму как.

Comment: @Gorets, спасибо за идею )

Comment: svn co не скачивает?

Comment: Что значит "изменили файл на сервере"? В `Subversion` есть понятие репозитория и понятие локальной рабочей копии. Репозиторий обычно хранится в формате `FSFS,` который не пригоден для ручного редактирования.

Comment: "На сервере" - на той стороне, где мы обычно производим update.

Comment: а как тогда у вас называется "эта сторона" ?

Comment: Есть локальная машина, есть веб-сервер. НА локальной машина обычно производится svn commit, затем на веб-сервере производим svn update. Что не ясно? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Все, понял. У вас есть `Subversion` репозиторий и "на сервере" расположен `checkout` какой-то ветки, который и отдается пользователем вашего сайта / сервиса.
- В таком случае **правильным** решением задачи было бы закоммитить ваше изменение как обычно (из локальной рабочей копии), а "на сервере" выполнить `svn revert . --recursive` и `svn update`.

Comment: svn revert конкретного файла, я правильно понимаю? Мне не нужно всё.

Answer (score -1):

В общем, пока ждал, ответ нашелся )
Значит так:

1. Копируем файл с сервера на свой локальный компьютер;
2. Производим егокоммит (если файл недоступен для коммита, венсите небольшое измнение,    например пробел в комментарии или просто комментарий);
3. На сервере делаем update файла. SVN поругается на конфликт;
4. Выбираем опцию tf;
5. Profit!

Вот и все ) Извиняюсь за лишний флуд, но кому-то может понадобится.